# Running Skype through Wine

Tags: wine, skype

So many of you probably know how the linux version of skype does not support a video conference call, for unknown reasons to me. So to handle this I have tried running it through Wine. I applied the edit on the desktop file as suggested [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31461). This gets skype to load, but it crashes quickly after. I get this backtrace from the crash:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000014 in 32-bit code (0x00dc3207).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00dc3207 ESP:0ee0e5c4 EBP:0ee0e5cc EFLAGS:00010282(  R- --  I S - - - )
 EAX:0ee0e5e0 EBX:0ee0e658 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000000
 ESI:0ee0e628 EDI:0479e6a4
Stack dump:
0x0ee0e5c4:  0ee0e5e0 00000000 0ee0e600 00dc3608
0x0ee0e5d4:  0ee0e5e0 c24a3710 0479e6a0 0ee0e658
0x0ee0e5e4:  00000000 0479e6a0 00000000 00000001
0x0ee0e5f4:  0ee0e6d8 0149ed31 00000000 0ee0e6e4
0x0ee0e604:  00e1dfb8 0ee0e628 047a264c 047a2644
0x0ee0e614:  0ee0e6a0 00000000 0479e6a0 0479e6a4
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 16-bit r-x
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00dc3207 in skype (+0x9c3207) (0x0ee0e5cc)
  1 0x00dc3608 in skype (+0x9c3607) (0x0ee0e600)
  2 0x00e1dfb8 in skype (+0xa1dfb7) (0x0ee0e6e4)
  3 0x01034b7b in skype (+0xc34b7a) (0x0ee0e724)
  4 0x00bb8618 in skype (+0x7b8617) (0x0ee0e73c)
  5 0x009a732b in skype (+0x5a732a) (0x0ee0e764)
  6 0x009a7420 in skype (+0x5a741f) (0x0ee0e778)
  7 0x00bb82dc in skype (+0x7b82db) (0x0ee0e78c)
  8 0x00bb76cf in skype (+0x7b76ce) (0x0ee0e8cc)
  9 0x00bb754a in skype (+0x7b7549) (0x0ee0e8f0)
  10 0x009a23ba in skype (+0x5a23b9) (0x0ee0e924)
  11 0x009a2550 in skype (+0x5a254f) (0x0ee0e974)
  12 0x0120cc56 in skype (+0xe0cc55) (0x0ee0e9ac)
  13 0x0120cd7e in skype (+0xe0cd7d) (0x0ee0e9b8)
  14 0x7bc84df0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0ee0e9c8)
  15 0x7bc87fc5 call_thread_func+0x104() in ntdll (0x0ee0ead8)
  16 0x7bc84dce RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0ee0eb08)
  17 0x7bc8ee99 in ntdll (+0x7ee98) (0x0ee0f358)
  18 0xf75861c3 start_thread+0xe2() in libpthread.so.0 (0x0ee0f428)
  19 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  20 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  21 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  22 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  23 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  24 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  25 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  26 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  27 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  28 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  29 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  30 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  31 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  32 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  33 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  34 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  35 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  36 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  37 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  38 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  39 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  40 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  41 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  42 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  43 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  44 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  45 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  46 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  47 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  48 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  49 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  50 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  51 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  52 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  53 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  54 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  55 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  56 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  57 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  58 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  59 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  60 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  61 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  62 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  63 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  64 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  65 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  66 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  67 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  68 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  69 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  70 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  71 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  72 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  73 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  74 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  75 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  76 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  77 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  78 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  79 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  80 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  81 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  82 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  83 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  84 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  85 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  86 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  87 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  88 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  89 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  90 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  91 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  92 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  93 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  94 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  95 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  96 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  97 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  98 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  99 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  100 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  101 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  102 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  103 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  104 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  105 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  106 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  107 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  108 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  109 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  110 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  111 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  112 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  113 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  114 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  115 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  116 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  117 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  118 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  119 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  120 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  121 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  122 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  123 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  124 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  125 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  126 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  127 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  128 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  129 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  130 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  131 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  132 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  133 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  134 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  135 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  136 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  137 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  138 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  139 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  140 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  141 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  142 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  143 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  144 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  145 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  146 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  147 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  148 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  149 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  150 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  151 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  152 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  153 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  154 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  155 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  156 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  157 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  158 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  159 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  160 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  161 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  162 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  163 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  164 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  165 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  166 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  167 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  168 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  169 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  170 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  171 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  172 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  173 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  174 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  175 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  176 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  177 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  178 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  179 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  180 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  181 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  182 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  183 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  184 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  185 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  186 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  187 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  188 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  189 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  190 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  191 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  192 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  193 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  194 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  195 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  196 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  197 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  198 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  199 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  200 0xf74b1dde __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x00dc3207: movl    0x14(%ecx),%ecx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (238 modules)
PE    400000- 375b000   Export          skype
PE  10000000-10021000   Deferred        updater
ELF 73d82000-73e3a000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  73da0000-73e3a000   \               msvcrt
ELF 74b8c000-74bf4000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  74b90000-74bf4000   \               dbghelp
ELF 74bf4000-74c64000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  74c00000-74c64000   \               riched20
ELF 74f07000-74f22000   Deferred        cryptnet<elf>
  \-PE  74f10000-74f22000   \               cryptnet
ELF 74f22000-74f65000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  74f30000-74f65000   \               rsaenh
ELF 74f65000-75100000   Deferred        mshtml<elf>
  \-PE  74f80000-75100000   \               mshtml
ELF 75214000-75248000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 75262000-752ec000   Deferred        ieframe<elf>
  \-PE  75270000-752ec000   \               ieframe
ELF 75323000-75371000   Deferred        libjpeg.so.8
ELF 753a3000-753bc000   Deferred        msftedit<elf>
  \-PE  753b0000-753bc000   \               msftedit
ELF 753bc000-75400000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  753c0000-75400000   \               usp10
ELF 76104000-761b0000   Deferred        jscript<elf>
  \-PE  76110000-761b0000   \               jscript
ELF 761b0000-767ff000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7a800000-7a931000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a931000   \               opengl32
ELF 7a943000-7a94d000   Deferred        libacl.so.1
ELF 7a94d000-7a963000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  7a950000-7a963000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7a963000-7a984000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE  7a970000-7a984000   \               cabinet
ELF 7aade000-7ab00000   Deferred        explorerframe<elf>
  \-PE  7aae0000-7ab00000   \               explorerframe
ELF 7ac59000-7ac66000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7addb000-7ae00000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7af03000-7af11000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7af11000-7af32000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7af33000-7af43000   Deferred        libnss_myhostname.so.2
ELF 7af7d000-7afa4000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE  7af80000-7afa4000   \               dxgi
ELF 7afa4000-7afb4000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7afb4000-7b05d000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7b05d000-7b168000   Deferred        libasound.so.2
ELF 7b173000-7b17c000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7b17c000-7b1b3000   Deferred        wbemprox<elf>
  \-PE  7b180000-7b1b3000   \               wbemprox
ELF 7b1b3000-7b2a9000   Deferred        quartz<elf>
  \-PE  7b1d0000-7b2a9000   \               quartz
ELF 7b602000-7b60d000   Deferred        libxcb-render.so.0
ELF 7b60d000-7b628000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7b628000-7b643000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7b643000-7b674000   Deferred        winealsa<elf>
  \-PE  7b650000-7b674000   \               winealsa
ELF 7b674000-7b69e000   Deferred        msvfw32<elf>
  \-PE  7b680000-7b69e000   \               msvfw32
ELF 7b69e000-7b6ee000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7b6a0000-7b6ee000   \               dsound
ELF 7b6ee000-7b77d000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7b77d000-7b800000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7b800000-7ba65000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba65000   \               kernel32
ELF 7ba65000-7ba6c000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7ba6c000-7ba7c000   Deferred        libxcb-randr.so.0
ELF 7ba7c000-7baab000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7baab000-7bb5b000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7bb5b000-7bb87000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7bb87000-7bc00000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf7000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcf7000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bcf8000-7bd00000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7be06000-7be1c000   Deferred        midimap<elf>
  \-PE  7be10000-7be1c000   \               midimap
ELF 7be1c000-7beaa000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7beaa000-7bf00000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7bf08000-7bf21000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7bf10000-7bf21000   \               msacm32
ELF 7bf21000-7bfa9000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-6.0.so
ELF 7c408000-7c411000   Deferred        libxcb-xfixes.so.0
ELF 7c411000-7c42c000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7c486000-7c48b000   Deferred        libxcb-shape.so.0
ELF 7c48b000-7c4a5000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c4a5000-7c500000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7c601000-7c609000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7c609000-7c61e000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7c61e000-7c627000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7c628000-7c62b000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7c62b000-7c62f000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7c62f000-7c635000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7c635000-7c64a000   Deferred        avicap32<elf>
  \-PE  7c640000-7c64a000   \               avicap32
ELF 7c64a000-7c672000   Deferred        devenum<elf>
  \-PE  7c650000-7c672000   \               devenum
ELF 7c672000-7c69c000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  7c680000-7c69c000   \               winepulse
ELF 7c69c000-7c6bf000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c6a0000-7c6bf000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7c6bf000-7c800000   Deferred        actxprxy<elf>
  \-PE  7c6e0000-7c800000   \               actxprxy
ELF 7c902000-7c90f000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7c90f000-7c924000   Deferred        wlanapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c910000-7c924000   \               wlanapi
ELF 7c924000-7c9b2000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7c930000-7c9b2000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7c9b2000-7c9ca000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7c9c0000-7c9ca000   \               wtsapi32
ELF 7c9ca000-7c9e0000   Deferred        winemapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c9d0000-7c9e0000   \               winemapi
ELF 7c9e0000-7ca0e000   Deferred        mapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7c9f0000-7ca0e000   \               mapi32
ELF 7ca0e000-7cb00000   Deferred        cryptui<elf>
  \-PE  7ca10000-7cb00000   \               cryptui
ELF 7cc00000-7cc04000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7cc04000-7cc07000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7cc07000-7ccc2000   Deferred        windowscodecs<elf>
  \-PE  7cc20000-7ccc2000   \               windowscodecs
ELF 7ccc2000-7ccd7000   Deferred        avrt<elf>
  \-PE  7ccd0000-7ccd7000   \               avrt
ELF 7ccd7000-7cd45000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7cce0000-7cd45000   \               setupapi
ELF 7cd45000-7cd5c000   Deferred        powrprof<elf>
  \-PE  7cd50000-7cd5c000   \               powrprof
ELF 7cd5c000-7cd87000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7cd60000-7cd87000   \               msacm32
ELF 7cd87000-7cdb6000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7cd90000-7cdb6000   \               netapi32
ELF 7cdb6000-7cdcf000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7cdcf000-7cdd5000   Deferred        libattr.so.1
ELF 7cdd5000-7cde9000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7cde0000-7cde9000   \               psapi
ELF 7cde9000-7ce1a000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7cdf0000-7ce1a000   \               secur32
ELF 7ce1a000-7ce3a000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ce20000-7ce3a000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7ce3a000-7ce58000   Deferred        pdh<elf>
  \-PE  7ce40000-7ce58000   \               pdh
ELF 7ce58000-7ce7f000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ce60000-7ce7f000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7cfbd000-7d030000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7d030000-7d065000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d065000-7d0a5000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d0a5000-7d0ba000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d0ba000-7d11d000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d11d000-7d14f000   Deferred        libcrypt.so.1
ELF 7d14f000-7d297000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7d297000-7d314000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d314000-7d319000   Deferred        libcap.so.2
ELF 7d319000-7d320000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7d35f000-7d365000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d365000-7d370000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d370000-7d383000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d383000-7d390000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d390000-7d3b6000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d3b6000-7d505000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d505000-7d51a000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d51a000-7d51e000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d51e000-7d524000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7d524000-7d52d000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d52d000-7d565000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d530000-7d565000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d565000-7d5f8000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d570000-7d5f8000   \               winex11
ELF 7d9b6000-7d9df000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d9df000-7da1b000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7da1b000-7da90000   Deferred        libpcre.so.1
ELF 7da90000-7dbb7000   Deferred        libglib-2.0.so.0
ELF 7dbb7000-7dc17000   Deferred        libharfbuzz.so.0
ELF 7dc17000-7dc56000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7dc56000-7dd16000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7dd17000-7dd23000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7dd23000-7dd2a000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7dd2a000-7dd4e000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dd30000-7dd4e000   \               imm32
ELF 7dd61000-7de19000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7dd70000-7de19000   \               winmm
ELF 7de19000-7df66000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7de30000-7df66000   \               wined3d
ELF 7df66000-7e04e000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7df70000-7e04e000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7e070000-7e074000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e087000-7e0c5000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7e090000-7e0c5000   \               d3d9
ELF 7e0c5000-7e0d9000   Deferred        shfolder<elf>
  \-PE  7e0d0000-7e0d9000   \               shfolder
ELF 7e0d9000-7e135000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7e0e0000-7e135000   \               oleacc
ELF 7e135000-7e15c000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e140000-7e15c000   \               mpr
ELF 7e15c000-7e173000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e174000-7e185000   Deferred        libbz2.so.1.0
ELF 7e185000-7e1be000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e190000-7e1be000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e1be000-7e23a000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7e1d0000-7e23a000   \               wininet
ELF 7e23a000-7e2b2000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e250000-7e2b2000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e2b2000-7e4f3000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2c0000-7e4f3000   \               shell32
ELF 7e4f3000-7e592000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7e500000-7e592000   \               urlmon
ELF 7e592000-7e5d1000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e5d1000   \               winspool
ELF 7e5d1000-7e6d1000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5e0000-7e6d1000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e6d1000-7e7a3000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6e0000-7e7a3000   \               crypt32
ELF 7e7a3000-7e7da000   Deferred        wintrust<elf>
  \-PE  7e7b0000-7e7da000   \               wintrust
ELF 7e7da000-7e85b000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e7f0000-7e85b000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e85b000-7e97b000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e870000-7e97b000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e97b000-7eaea000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e990000-7eaea000   \               user32
ELF 7eaea000-7eb5f000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb00000-7eb5f000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eb5f000-7ec9b000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb80000-7ec9b000   \               ole32
ELF 7ec9b000-7edd0000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7ecb0000-7edd0000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7ef59000-7ef67000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef67000-7efb5000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efb7000-7efbe000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7efbe000-7efd2000   Deferred        olepro32<elf>
  \-PE  7efc0000-7efd2000   \               olepro32
ELF 7efd2000-7efe6000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7efe0000-7efe6000   \               msimg32
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f7370000-f7374000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF f7374000-f7378000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f7379000-f737e000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f73c9000-f7580000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7580000-f759d000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f759e000-f7765000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7766000-f778a000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f778c000-f778d000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe
    00000077   -2
    00000076   -2
    00000075    0
    00000074    0
    0000006d   -1
    0000006c    0
    0000006b    0
    0000006a    0 <==
    00000069    0
    00000025    0
    00000066    0
    00000065    0
    0000005a    0
    00000054    0
    0000004a    0
    00000049    0
    00000048    0
    0000000d    0
    0000000b    0
    00000047   15
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    2
    00000043    0
    00000042   -1
    00000041    0
    00000040    0
    0000003f   -1
    0000003e    2
    0000003d   -1
    0000003c   -1
    0000003b    0
    0000003a    1
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    00000035    0
    00000033    0
    00000032    0
    00000031    0
    00000030    0
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    0000004c    0
    00000024    0
    0000001c    0
    00000016    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001b    0
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001a    0
00000020 Updater.exe
    00000068    0
    0000004b    0
    00000067    0
    00000063    0
    00000061    0
    0000005e    0
    0000005c    0
    0000005b    0
    00000058    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000021    0
00000022 explorer.exe
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    00000023    0
0000004d rpcss.exe
    00000057    0
    00000056    0
    00000055    0
    00000053    0
    00000052    0
    00000051    0
    0000004f    0
    0000004e    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.7.43 (Staging)
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.1.2-2-ARCH
```

System info:

```
steven ~ $ uname -a
Linux serenity 4.1.2-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 15 08:30:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am wondering what a solution to this problem might be. Or another way to get multi video conferencing through Skype, as that is my objective.

Comment: Did you tried suggestions in https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31461 ? 
In any case, it seems that "Video calls" do not work under wine.

Comment: I actually linked that exact same page in the OP. About trying their hack.

Comment: Crap, I did miss the video call part. Thanks. It still crashes though. And is there another way to resolve this?